# FormArray with HostListener in Directive

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm creating my inputs form within loop:

```
  <tr formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let vatCat of items.controls; let i = index">
            <td [formGroupName]="i">
              <input name="symbol" minlength="1" maxlength="1" [(ngModel)]="symbol" appUppercase type="text" formControlName="symbol">
            </td>
            <td [formGroupName]="i">
              <input name="value"  type="number" [ngModel]="0" formControlName="value">
            </td>
            <td [formGroupName]="i">
              <span class="table-remove">
                <button (click)="removeItem(i)" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0">Usuń</button>
              </span>
            </td>
....
```

Then I had to change every value in symbol input ot uppercase so I created an directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel][appUppercase]'
})
export class UppercaseDirective {
  @Output() ngModelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  value: any;

  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInputChange($event) {
    this.value = $event.target.value.toUpperCase();
    this.ngModelChange.emit(this.value);
  }
}
```

It works great until I add a new form, this is how my model looks like:

```
 formArray = this.formBuilder.group({
    items: this.formBuilder.array([])
  });

 buildItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      symbol: new FormControl('', this.vatCategoryValidation.bind(this)),
      value: new FormControl('', this.vatValueValidation.bind(this))
    });
  }
 addItem() {
    this.items.push(this.buildItem());
  }
```

There are currently two issues, the first one is that @Output value propagate to every each input instead of this one related to it. Second is an error `xpression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ng-valid: false'. Current value: 'ng-valid: true'.`

[image] 
Is it possible to make it works together?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I make it work, solved two problems at once by changing a little my Directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appUppercase]'
})
export class UppercaseDirective {
  @Output() ngModelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  value: any;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('input') onInputChange() {
    this.el.nativeElement.value = this.el.nativeElement.value.toUpperCase();
  }
}
```